Build an older openssl in cmake?
I need an older openssl (1_0_2u) than is available through the Fedora package manager (3.2.2). Currently I use ExternalProject and make an interface library, but I wonder if there isn't a better way via FetchContent and somehow pointing FindOpenSSL at it, is this possible? I originally thought the cmake stuff was provided by my distro and was basically custom for the package they shipped, but I thought to do a dnf repoquery -l openssl-devel, and it doesn't look like that's the case.
Do I need a fully built openssl to use FindOpenSSL? If so, is there much point in using it?
Here's how I do everything at the moment, for reference:
include(ExternalProject)

set(OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/openssl-install)

ExternalProject_Add(openssl_
  GIT_REPOSITORY     https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
  GIT_TAG            OpenSSL_${OPENSSL_VERSION}
  GIT_SHALLOW        ON
  BUILD_IN_SOURCE    ON
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND  ./config no-shared --prefix=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
  BUILD_COMMAND      make
  INSTALL_COMMAND    make install
  UPDATE_COMMAND     ""
)

add_library(openssl INTERFACE)


# Interface for nicer use.

add_dependencies(openssl openssl_)

set_property(TARGET openssl
  PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS
  -I${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/include)

set_property(TARGET openssl
  PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS
  -L${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib)

set_property(TARGET openssl
  PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES
  libssl.a
  libcrypto.a)


Is there a reason not to use a package manager like Conan for this? Conan has this version: https://conan.io/center/recipes/openssl

This is me being lazy, but does OpenSSL ship with a CMakeListst.txt? I feel like you have to run their custom configure script and then make. In which case CMake's rudimentary package management is out.

@jabaa That might be an idea - I don't have a good impression of conan so I went down the manual route, I think that's more to do with the places I've seen it used massively over-complicating things though, so might investigate that.

Using Conan in a project is usually only a conanfile.txt with a list of dependencies. It looks far more complicated than it actually is.

If you're looking for an alternative, I prefer vcpkg as my C++ package manager, and they also have many versions of OpenSSL available. My take on conan is that's it's a meta build system with package management as a side effect.

@sweenish thanks, will check out the package manager - and I can't see any files in the openssl source for the version I need, I think it does for later versions

Take care using the 1x series of OpenSSL as I am not sure the security fixes were back-ported. See also OpenSSL Vulnerabilities
